# Quais as reais diferenças em criar um projeto com Expo e sem Expo?

Tags: react, react-native, expo

Recentemente vi vários itens que diferenciavam um projeto com ou sem Expo, porém atualmente a Expo inclui muitas coisas em que antes precisávamos mexer em módulos nativos: SQLite, manipulação de imagens, câmera, *splash screens* etc.

Então gostaria de saber o seguinte:

- Vale a pena hoje em dia iniciar um projeto sem Expo?
- Eu consigo gerar um arquivo `.apk` com a Expo? Sem que fique
  preso a ela e/ou não pague nada a mais por isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Resumo

Se vale a pena ou não iniciar um projeto com Expo, depende muito. Dependendo das necessidades do seu app, **precisará** ir apenas com React Native. Dependendo, pode ou não escolher o Expo.

Em 2021, o Expo está trabalhando para permitir que [dependências nativas sejam adicionadas](https://blog.expo.io/expo-managed-workflow-in-2021-d1c9b68aa10), então talvez no futuro não exista mais um projeto que não seja possível de fazer com o Expo, se isso permitir também que você modifique código nativo, como num projeto RN sem Expo.

De forma geral, você pode usar tudo do Expo gratuitamente, posteriormente realizando um `expo eject` e seguindo a sua própria vida. O único ponto aqui é que as *builds* realizadas no *managed workflow* se forem feitas através de uma conta gratuita, terá uma fila de espera (nunca vi demorar mais do que 30 minutos na fila).

Tem um resumo com tabela nesta resposta indicando as limitações do Expo no *managed workflow*. O *bare workflow* não terá muitas limitações, como você pode ver na tabela, mas não vale a pena iniciar um app no Expo se você já sabe que terá que ejetar para o *bare workflow*. Escrevi minha experiência com Expo e React Native ao final da resposta.

---

## O que é o Expo?

Gostaria de explicar o que é o Expo aqui, mas deixaria a resposta maior ainda. Entretanto, devo resumir para contextualizar o resto da resposta:

O [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo)) é um *framework open-source* e uma plataforma para aplicativos React universais. É um conjunto de ferramentas e serviços criados em torno de plataformas React Native e nativas para ajudar desde o desenvolvimento até atualizações [Over The Air (OTA)](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/) e a geração do `.apk`, `.aab` e `.ipa` para que você possa colocar seu app nas lojas Play Store e App Store.

O Expo permite o desenvolvimento de aplicativos iOS, Android e web a partir da mesma base de código JavaScript / TypeScript.

As duas abordagens para construir aplicativos com ferramentas Expo são chamadas de [fluxos de trabalho "gerenciados" (*managed workflows*) e "simples" (*bare workflows*)](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/). Segue abaixo um breve resumo, já que é preciso entender isso para responder a pergunta.

### Managed workflow

Com o fluxo de trabalho gerenciado, você apenas escreve JavaScript / TypeScript e as ferramentas e serviços Expo cuidam de todo o resto para você. Os apps são construídos usando o [expo-cli](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/expo-cli/), o aplicativo Expo ([Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent), [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/br/app/expo-client/id982107779)) no seu dispositivo móvel, além de serviços como [notificações *push*](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/), [*build*](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/) e [atualizações Over The Air](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/).

### Bare workflow

No fluxo de trabalho simples, você tem controle total sobre todos os aspectos do projeto nativo, e as ferramentas e serviços do Expo são um pouco mais limitados. O desenvolvedor tem controle total, mas com grandes poderes vem grandes responsabilidades, então deverá lidar com a complexidade que vem com isso. Você pode usar a maioria das APIs do Expo SDK, mas o serviço de compilação e a configuração fácil com `app.json` / `app.config.js` ainda não são suportados.

Você pode sair do *managed workflow* para o *bare workflow* usando `expo eject`.

---

## Quando não usar Expo?

Como não existe uma situação do tipo "Quando usar o Expo?", é mais fácil entender quando não usá-lo. Se seus requisitos não se encaixarem em nenhuma situação abaixo, fica a seu critério de usar o Expo ou não. Se seu aplicativo for muito simples, não se encaixar nas limitações abaixo, e você está iniciando com React Native agora, o Expo pode te ajudar bastante - isso aconteceu comigo.

Em *[Limitations](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/)* você encontrará uma lista atualizada de limitações do Expo. Vou resumir abaixo o que está na documentação, já que ela é em inglês, separando entre *Managed workflow* e *Bare workflow*. Note que as limitações do *managed workflow* **não são** limitações do *bare workflow* (não há intersecções).

### Managed workflow

- Nem todas APIs iOS e Android estão disponíveis. Exemplo: Bluetooth.
- O SDK não suporta todos os tipos de execução de código em segundo plano. Exemplo: áudio com os controles de reprodução do sistema operacional.
- Limitação no tamanho mínimo do aplicativo. Para iOS é `20mb` e para Android `15mb`.
- Não é possível adicionar bibliotecas de terceiro que envolvem códigos nativos. Algumas dependências assim estão inclusas no Expo, como o `react-native-reanimated`, mas você não pode adicionar uma que não esteja no SDK.
- O único serviço de notificação *push* com suporte é o serviço de notificação Expo.
- As versões mínimas suportadas para os Sistemas Operacionais são Android 5 (API 21) e iOS 10.0.
- As *builds* gratuitas geralmente são colocadas em fila. Mas você pode gerar as *builds* [no seu próprio CI](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/turtle-cli/).
- As atualizações (JS e *assets*) para atualizações e compilações OTA são limitadas por tamanho (até aproximadamente `50mb`).

### Bare workflow

- O serviço de *build* só funciona no *managed workflow*. Entretanto, você pode realizar a *build* como faria num projeto RN comum, por conta própria.
- A configuração deve ser feita em cada projeto nativo (e.g. Android e iOS) em vez de uma única vez com o `app.json`.

---

## Comparações: React Native puro vs Expo

Essa tabela foi desenvolvida por mim, agregando informações de vários lugares diferentes, então **não contém todas as possibilidades**, apenas as que encontrei ou lembrei.

| Funcionalidade | React Native | Expo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Programar com JavaScript / TypeScript | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Modificar código nativo (Android / iOS) | ✔️ | ⚠️ *Bare workflow* |
| Adicionar bibliotecas de terceiros com código nativo | ✔️ | ⚠️ *Bare workflow* |
| Bluetooth API | ✔️ | ⚠️ [*Feature Request*](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-api) <sup>1</sup> |
| Compras dentro do aplicativo | ✔️ | ⚠️ [*Feature Request*](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/in-app-purchases) <sup>1</sup> |
| WebRTC | ✔️ | ⚠️ [*Feature Request*](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/webrtc) <sup>1</sup> |
| Suporte NFC | ✔️ | ⚠️ [*Feature Request*](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/nfc-support) <sup>1</sup> |
| Reprodução de áudio com controles do SO | ✔️ | ⚠️ [*Feature Request*](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/audio-playback-in-background) <sup>1</sup> |
| Hermes no Android | ✔️ [v0.60.1+](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0601) | ⚠️ [*Feature Request*](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/enabling-hermes) <sup>1</sup> |
| Hermes no iOS | ✔️ [v0.64.0+](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/214) | *desconhecido, provavelmente igual acima* |
| Permissão `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` opcional no Android | ✔️ | ⚠️ [SDK 40+](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-40-is-now-available-d4d73e67da33) |
| Suporta iOS 10.0 | ❌ <sup>2</sup> | ⚠️ [SDK 41+ iOS 11](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-41-12cc5232f2ef) |
| Suporta Android API 16 ~ 20 | ⚠️ [v0.64.0+ API 21](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/214) | ⚠️ API 21 no *Managed workflow* <sup>3</sup> |

<sup>1. Em geral, o que possui uma *Feature Request* para o *managed workflow* funciona no *bare workflow*, porque você passa a poder modificiar/incluir código nativo.</sup>
<sup>2. Não encontrei a versão do React Native que suporta o iOS 10.0, no README.md é mencionado apenas o requerimento mínimo da versão 11, de acordo com [esse commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6cd31be00eb6854bf2c2cc0d76f4456d3b773d5a) de Jan/2021.</sup>
<sup>3. O *bare workflow* do Expo suporta a mesma API do Android que a versão do React Native utilizada.</sup>

### Serviços

Como já mencionado anteriormente, o Expo fornece alguns serviços. Isso significa que pelo simples fato de usar o Expo você já possui um acesso facilitado a tudo isso, enquanto que sem o Expo você precisaria utilizar algum recurso de terceiros.

| Serviço | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| [Atualizações Over The Air (OTA)](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/) | Atualização de código JavaScript sem precisar atualizar na loja (Play Store / App Store). |
| [Build de apps na nuvem](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/) | O Expo realiza a *build* de apps no *managed workflow* nos servidores deles, tanto de iOS quanto de Android, então você pode realizar a *build* para o iOS mesmo sem um MacOS. |
| [Notificações Push](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/) | Você pode enviar notificações *push* com o Expo utilizando o pacote `expo-notifications`. |

---

## O Expo vai incluir mais coisas?

Se você usar o Expo, dependerá do Expo para atualizar as dependências, a versão do React Native e ter novas funcionalidades. A equipe do Expo é bem capacitada e [trabalha em novas funcionalidades](https://expo.canny.io/), [algumas sugeridas pela comunidade](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests). A equipe também realiza um trabalho ativo no [GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo) e no [fórum do Expo](https://forums.expo.io/), além do [blog](https://blog.expo.io/) onde fazem anúncios. Então sim, o Expo está constantemente evoluindo e incluindo mais coisas conforme avança na versão de seu SDK.

---

## Minha experiência: Expo vs React Native

Publiquei um app feito com Expo e um feito com React Native (sem Expo). Antes de desenvolver cada app, fiz um app de testes para entender como funciona (o Expo e o RN) e como poderia fazer o que eu precisava (leitura de arquivos, escrita, chamada de API, navegação etc.), e recomendo quem pretende aprender a mexer com RN fazer a mesma coisa.

Desenvolver um app em RN foi bem tranquilo, tive que aprender algumas coisas além do que sabia quando fiz com o Expo, que também precisei aprender algumas coisas, já que foi meu primeiro app assim. Esse é o caminho que recomendo para quem tem tempo, você terá mais conhecimento para fazer o app real e o processo de desenvolvimento e a usabilidade provavelmente serão melhores.

Agora, escolher entre Expo ou React Native fica a gosto dos desenvolvedores. Se o Expo permite você fazer o que precisa ser feito e você não possui experiência com RN, o desenvolvimento será mais rápido. Se você prefere entender melhor as coisas, tem tempo, quer mais flexibilidade ou as limitações do Expo te incomodam, siga com o React Native "puro" :)

Answer (score 9):

**Projeto com Expo**

O Expo faz o papel de compilador do seu app: ele substitui a Android SDK e o Xcode por um método próprio, portanto, você não precisa configurar nada. Entretanto, o Expo nos 'limita' (dificulta bastante) na parte de alterar configurações ou inserir pacotes que modifiquem arquivos específicos do Android ou iOs. Portanto, ele pode ajudar muito já que hoje em dia dá acesso a inúmeras funções nativas mas, por outro lado, pode acabar limitando a instalação de algumas dependências que necessitam que o app esteja 'ejetado'.

**Projeto sem Expo**

É o projeto que será compilado usando as SDK de cada plataforma. Permite customizar muitos aspectos do build e é meu preferido pois utilizo algumas dependências que necessitam acesso às configurações de OS na hora de buildar.

---

- Recomendo a criação de um projeto sem o Expo já que inúmeros pacotes que você pode acabar querendo usar no desenvolvimento tenham problemas com ele. Além do mais, você terá controle total no build do app e não dependerá de uma plataforma para compilar seu app.
- Sim, você pode gerar um arquivo .apk com o Expo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, um ultimo item se possível, estava pensando em iniciar com o Expo e em ultimo caso, se precisasse de alterações no código nativo, ejetasse o app, é uma boa ideia ou essa ejeção pode me trazer problemas?

Comment: Sim, você pode ejetar sua aplicação a qualquer momento do desenvolvimento, apenas tenha em mente que o comportamento da sua aplicação pode mudar dependendo de como foram feitas certas funcionalidades. Por exemplo, tive alguns problemas de layout quando ejetei minha aplicação e há casos mais sérios em que funcionalidades baseadas dentro do que o Expo fornece podem aparentar problemas ao interagir diretamente com as SDK's. Não possuo experiência o suficiente para afirmar que causará ou não problemas, apenas tenha em mente que podem surgir inconvenientes, por isso, recomenda-se utilizar nativo.